# MySQL compare if first and second part of the string are the same

Tags: mysql

Alright so I have to make a query to select all emails that have same domain name and name.

For example I have situations like

myname@myname.com or test@test.com.

I want to select all rows that are like these.

I tried like LIKE operand but couldn't manage much.

Comment: `select * from t where email like '%@test.com'`.

Comment: @TheImpaler but I do not know what's the first or 2nd part either. For example it can be combination "test@test.com" or maybe "myname@myname.com", I am for a pattern sql

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It seems you want to extract parts of the parameters and compose a regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the name and the domain:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1) = 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1), '.', 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3f8f74db0d1aa779b07488ebe9a80da5).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point:

```sql
SELECT email
FROM email_addresses
WHERE email like CONCAT('%@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1), '.%')
;
```

The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function splits the email address to get the part before '@', in order to use it with the `LIKE` operator.
The problem is relate to the final part of the email address, as it could be .com, .net, .org...or an email address could be x.ross@x.ross.com.
You can see the results in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5741ea/3/0)